# Transfer IPA file to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, cydia

I'm using Cydia Impactor and wish to copy an IPA file from my PC to iPhone 5 running iOS 10.3.3.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Plug your iPhone into your PC
2. Open Cydia Impactor
3. Drag the .ipa file onto Cydia Impactor
4. When prompted, enter your Apple-ID email address and password